# Does using cat5e cables yield any disadvantages in combination with cat6/cat6a network?

Tags: networking, ethernet, switch, gigabit-ethernet

If I were to have a fully compliant cat6 or cat6a network running through my walls... that is to say, wires and jacks... What would be the concequence of plugging a cat5e wire into one of the jacks? I'm assuming that it would still run at cat5e standards, but obviously not cat6/6a standards because the whole connection is not cat6.

I only ask because it seems silly to me to make a bunch of cat6 patch cables for connections that don't really matter, like standard desktop computers and other equipment. Or will doing so hamper the whole network?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: my answer assumes you have plugged all these Cat6 cables into an ethernet switch or router.  My answer also assumes all cables have been pinned and terminated correctly.

> If I were to have a fully compliant cat6 or cat6a network running through my walls... that is to say, wires and jacks... What would be the concequence of plugging a cat5e wire into one of the jacks?

Speaking as a professional network engineer, the only meaningful consequence is possibly lower speed negotiated on that particular link.

> I'm assuming that it would still run at cat5e standards, but obviously not cat6/6a standards because the whole connection is not cat6.

Correct assumption

> will doing so hamper the whole network?

Nope.  Furthermore, the compelling reason for using wiring rated higher than Cat5e is 1GigE or 10GE speeds; however, [Cat5e is capable of 1GE as well](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_5e_cable).

Comment: Moreover, having CAT6 cables + CAT6 jacks does not equal CAT6 compliant system... Installation matters, a lot! So unless you paid high $$$ for testing, I wouldn't assume that the in-wall cabling would ever support 10gbps.

Answer (score 1):

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_6_cable), CAT 6 standard:

> Category 6 cable, commonly referred to as Cat 6, is a cable standard
>   for Gigabit Ethernet and other network physical layers that is
>   backward compatible with the Category 5/5e and Category 3 cable
>   standards. Compared with Cat 5 and Cat 5e, Cat 6 features more
>   stringent specifications for crosstalk and system noise. The cable
>   standard **provides performance of up to 250 MHz** and is suitable for
>   10BASE-T, 100BASE-TX (Fast Ethernet), 1000BASE-T/1000BASE-TX (Gigabit
>   Ethernet) and 10GBASE-T (10-Gigabit Ethernet).

And [Cat 5e](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_5_cable):

> The specification for Category 5 cable was defined in
>   ANSI/TIA/EIA-568-A, with clarification in TSB-95.
>   These documents specified performance characteristics and test
>   requirements for frequencies of up to 100 MHz.

Assuming these premisses, you can see that the main phisical reason to addopt a Cat 6/6a wire and conectors is the **possibility to use more than 100 MHz to send/receive data signals**, what you will actually ned only on Gigabit speed(such as [1000BaseTX Gigabit ethernet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1000BASE-TX#1000BASE-TX)).

Adding Cat 6/6e conectors on a Cat 5e wire network will only provide the capability to use up to 250MHz into your conectors, what wouldn't be noticeable in terms of speed on any way(unless your Cat 5E conectors are bad) because the main device on a wired network is acutally the wire, not the connectors. Actually, if you had a Cat 6 wire network using Cat 5e conectors then you could maybe see your Gigabit Ethernet running Ok(Ok not means good or perfect, you could see a lot of packet loss).

If you want to use a Cat 6/6a network, then you should use all components of this standard(cables, connectors and actives) and not only one of this component alone.

Comment: I don't know if it was clear or not, but I meant to imply that the whole network in the walls and jacks would be cat6, but the patch cable from the wall to the device might be (for some, but not all of the devices) cat5e. I understand fully that this would make the wiring moot for that run - but would it affect other connections between a different jack and the switch it's plugged into?

Comment: What do you mean with "affect other connections between a different jack and the switch it's plugged into"? Whathever it is, if you change any component of entire path of a Cat 6/6e network you may(probabilly will) have some problem with your Gigabit network(unless you are using FastEthernet 100Mbs over your Cat 6/6e network). The explanation is just due t the fact that any lower component on your netowk will work as a filter to high frequencies(from 100 to 250MHz).

Comment: Well... if I plug a printer into the network with a cat5e cable... Will that hamper other devices, even if they're all plugged in using cat6?

Comment: Gigabit is fine on cat5e. It's really only when you start considering 10 gigabit that the difference matters.